# Setting up a subdomain with IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, subdomain

I have a web site that is currently hosted at IP address 11.11.11.111 (this is a fake address, just for communicating). I can successfully access the site via www.mydomain.com. I now want to allow a user to access m.mydomain.com.

This url needs to use the same IP Address. It will be hosted on the same web server, but as its own application. Currently, I have created a new CNAME record with my GoDaddy account. That record has the following properties:

**CNAME**

```
Host: m
Points To: @
```

On my web server, I have a web application called "Mobile". This application has a site binding with the following properties:

**Site Binding**

```
Type: http
Host Name: m.mydomain.com
Port: 60
IP Address: 11.11.11.111
```

When I type "m.mydomain.com" into my browser, I see the original website. I do not see the mobile version. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

digging this one up, but you're using non-standard port 60 (standard HTTP port is 80), so most likely you can only get to your site via the url: http://m.mydomain.com:60